# output the_field of related posts with ACF Relationship

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

and first off all, thanks for help.

I have to following code to display related posts from one custom post type to another with ACF Relationships.

what i want to know, is it possible and how can i rewrite the code, to output any custom field of the related post that i have selected with the relationship field?

```
<?php 
$posts = get_field('product_id');

    if( $posts ): ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach( $posts as $p ): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $p->ID ); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

like i do here, is:

`echo get_permalink( $p->ID );`

i want to echo:

`the_field('field_name')`

regards,
Axel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation of the [the_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) function you'll notice that it can take the post/page ID as the second parameter so you can retrieve the field value of a specific post/page field:

> **Parameters**
>
> `the_field($selector, [$post_id], [$format_value]);`
>
> - `$selector` (string) (Required) The field name or field key.
> - `$post_id` (mixed) (Optional) The post ID where the value is saved. Defaults to the current post.
> - `$format_value` (bool) (Optional) Whether to apply formatting logic. Defaults to true.

So, for example:

```
<?php
$posts = get_field('product_id');

if( $posts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $p ): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $p->ID ); ?></a>

            <?php the_field('field_name', $p->ID); ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```